# How can I label my data points according to defined ranges?

Tags: r, intervals, cut

I have a dataframe **df** and I set interval points which are saved in a vector **pts**. Now I want to label my data into these intervals. I tried using the cut() function, but I always get the mistake, that x is not numeric, even though I converted it to numeric.

My dataframe **df**

```
        date    amount
1    2012-07-01 2.3498695
2    2012-08-01 0.6984866
3    2012-09-01 0.9079118
4    2012-10-01 2.8858218
5    2012-11-01 1.2406948
6    2012-12-01 2.3140496
7    2013-01-01 1.5904573
8    2013-02-01 3.2531825
9    2013-03-01 4.2962963
10   2013-04-01 3.3287101
11   2013-05-01 3.7698413
12   2013-06-01 1.4376997
13   2013-07-01 5.0687285
14   2013-08-01 4.4520548
15   2013-09-01 5.5063913
16   2013-10-01 5.5676856
17   2013-11-01 6.2686567
18   2013-12-01 11.021069
```

My vector **pts** with column **Min** with interval points

```
pts$Min
[1]  3  6 11
```

My new dataframe should look like this:

```
    date     amount      IntervalRange
1    2012-07-01 2.3498695    1
2    2012-08-01 0.6984866    1
3    2012-09-01 0.9079118    1
4    2012-10-01 2.8858218    2
5    2012-11-01 1.2406948    2
6    2012-12-01 2.3140496    2
7    2013-01-01 1.5904573    3
8    2013-02-01 3.2531825    3
9    2013-03-01 4.2962963    3
10   2013-04-01 3.3287101    3
11   2013-05-01 3.7698413    3
12   2013-06-01 1.4376997    4
13   2013-07-01 5.0687285    4
14   2013-08-01 4.4520548    4
15   2013-09-01 5.5063913    4
16   2013-10-01 5.5676856    4
17   2013-11-01 6.2686567    4
18   2013-12-01 11.021069    4
```

SO, I tried this:

```
df_cut <- data.frame(as.numeric(df$date), "IntervalRange" = cut(
                                                df,
                                                breaks=pts$Min))
```

Which results in this **error message**:

> Error in cut.default(df, breaks = pts$Min) :    'x' must be numeric

**My questions now are**:

1. Why do I get this error message? I already changed it to numeric...
2. Can I achieve my desired output by using the **cut()** and **findIntervals()** functions also when using other datasets with other interval points?

Comment: `as.numeric(cut(df$amount, breaks = c(0, 3, 6, 11)))`

Comment: @RonakShah Nevermind, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @RonakShah Does not work

Comment: `x` in this error message should be a numeric vector. You've instead supplied `df` to that argument, which is a data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lacking the value (or the column) in the cut function. Your command should be

```
data.frame(as.numeric(df$date), "IntervalRange" = cut(df$amount,  breaks=pts$Min))
```

Hope this helps!